# NAudio Universal: Timed out waiting for event

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, windows-10-universal, naudio

I am unable to play decoded opus packets using `Naudio` for Windows Universal. The sound plays for a split second then stops with an exception. The exception I receive is `InvalidOperation - Timed out waiting for event`.

Here is my code:

```
public void ForStackOverFlow()
{
    var waveOut = new WasapiOutRT(AudioClientShareMode.Shared, 200);
    waveOut.PlaybackStopped += WaveOut_PlaybackStopped;
    var opusDecoder = OpusDecoder.Create(48000, 1);
    var ms = new MemoryStream();

    var voiceData1 = "3OxQRhb / datLhcmWgOhYPrYGwxyciCulHDwJl8RmJHkdWVcENoAYvgLtcFn0LBLbLJ2jHRPv8Wb / oZSsTp3oJbllORxffNIyZO1TCCf2L + dkN5AMKRmiIyYaJQrh5Bt4ucLfNskhwKwz / CfLV7RRTZrBJM + 0AqBXS9dt3 + yeBofItCGUm / GCT94pW5fl9U7Zez + RodOAzyEemdCS + Zfpquw0XctnM0L / b1llt3oHZOpot1BUY + tDyXmSNbcfxPjYmVvPT2y4aQ ==";
    var sample = Convert.FromBase64String(voiceData1);

    int frameSize = 1920;  

    short[] outputBuffer = new short[frameSize];
    var decodedLen = opusDecoder.Decode(sample, 0, sample.Length, outputBuffer, 0, frameSize, false);

    short[] finalOutput = new short[frameSize];
    Array.Copy(outputBuffer, finalOutput, finalOutput.Length); 

    var audioBytes = AudioMath.ShortsToBytes(finalOutput, 0, finalOutput.Length); 

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AUDIOBYTES:" + Convert.ToBase64String(audioBytes));

    ms.Write(audioBytes, 0, audioBytes.Length);

    ms.Flush();
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    IWaveProvider provider = new RawSourceWaveStream(ms, new WaveFormat(48000, 16, 1));
    waveOut.Init(provider);
    waveOut.Play();
}

private void WaveOut_PlaybackStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
{
    //event fires with exception.
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What library did you use for `OpusDecoder` and `AudioMath`?

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that here you got the length of the result:

```
var decodedLen = opusDecoder.Decode
```

If yes, why don't you create the `finalOutput` array with that variable, and use the `framesize` constant instead?

```
short[] finalOutput = new short[frameSize];
```

Shouldn't this line be like this:

```
short[] finalOutput = new short[decodedLen];
```